# Cython pycrypto performance

Tags: python, encryption, aes, cython, pycrypto

I have some problem with time encryption PyCrypto AES-128. My setup Raspberry Pi 2 + Python and other stuff. I'm trying to encrypt a message, but for some reason, it process takes a large part of processor time. That's why I decided to try using Cython and write the tests to compare my time benefit what I got.

main_py.py

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

key = "..."
plain_text = "..."
enc_obj = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)

def test():
    enc_obj.encrypt(plain_text)
```

main_cy.pyx

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

cdef char* key = "..."
cdef char* plain_text = "..."
cdef object enc_obj = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)

cpdef void test():
    enc_obj.encrypt(plain_text)
```

test.py

```
import timeit

cy = timeit.timeit('main_cy.test()', setup='import main_cy', number=100000)
py = timeit.timeit('main_py.test()', setup="import main_py", number=100000)

print(cy, py)
print(py / cy)
```

And result what I got cython encrypted slower than python. If I'm doing something wrong let me know, because I just start to learn cython. Maybe you have some proposals like use other lib or use C lib and import in cython program, please let me know, but I must use AES with lookup tables optimization.

Comment: Literally all the work is done by the crypto module. The only thing Cython changes here is how some strings are initialized (which should be quick anyway). There is absolutely nothing to be gained by using Cython here.

Comment: @DavidW yes, but it is just a test, not my real program. Did I get the interesting result, yep, but why that it works slower?

Comment: It's most likely slower because it has to create a Python string from a character array each time while the pure Python version already has the string. That should be the only difference. Try making `plain_text` a `str` or `object` and it'll probably be closer.

Comment: pycrypto uses libtom (tomcrypt) for its crypto which is a C library. You really don't need to use cython

Comment: @DavidW thanks, I will try.